# Can you launch an android app as an ARC app through Android studio?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, google-chrome-arc

I would like to know if there is a way to launch and/or build an ARC app from Android Studio without having to manually use ARC welder every time.

It can be pretty cumbersome to do this manually during development, and especially during a release when you have to do the same operation to ~15 different flavors of the same app. Is there anything in to works that solves this issue like a gradle extension or something.

Comment: The actual ZIP file created by ARC Welder appears to be mostly boilerplate. The obvious variable bits are the `icon.png` (96x96 px edition of your launcher icon), the APK itself in `vendor/chromium/crx/`, and the `arc_metadata` portion of the `manifest.json` file. The latter is where your ARC Welder settings go, like the form factor and orientation. Cooking up a Gradle task that builds a ZIP file as part of the overall build seems doable. It would be unofficial, and you would need to track changes to the ZIP contents as ARC Welder evolves.

Comment: That's a good idea, I will try to do this when I have some free time and share it here.

Comment: This probably will not get done for a while(lack of time).  @CommonsWare if you want to post your comment in an answer I will accept it. I think it is good enough to close this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of the time of this writing, no official automated ARC building solution has been offered. It's ARC Welder or bust.

That being said, since the Chrome extension (CRX) has an open specification, and since the contents of the CRX (as a ZIP file) are easy to examine, reverse-engineering what ARC Welder does and creating a Gradle plugin or something would not be that difficult for somebody with the itch to scratch.

When I examined it, the obvious variable bits were the `icon.png` (96x96 px edition of your launcher icon), the APK itself in `vendor/chromium/crx/`, and the `arc_metadata` portion of the `manifest.json` file. The latter is where your ARC Welder settings go, like the form factor and orientation.

Of course, any homebrew solution would need to track changes to ARC Welder to ensure that it kept producing valid ARC files.