# Controlling Arc From The Command Line

Tags: google-chrome-arc

Can arc be scripted at all from the command line?  For instance, is there a command I could run which produces the same behavior as "Add your APK".  Something like:

```
arc -add /path/to/app.apk -removeExisting -metadata="{enableExternalDirectory: true, value=/path/to/external/directory}"
```

If not, maybe registry values which do the same thing?

If so, where do I find all the available commands?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30247598/115145

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare  Have you tried that solution at all?  My first pass at it caused the existing apk to get removed and nothing put in it's place (no longer in chrome launcher and no longer chrome://extensions).  I updated the apk in that file, and updated the json with the new apk name, app name, package name, etc.

Comment: If you mean "have I written a script to do what I described in my answer", no, as I haven't had the need. That being said, you would probably have to install the modified CRX the same way you would install any other Chrome extension. And, nowadays, that's actually more difficult, given that Google has been blocking side-loaded Chrome extensions IIRC.

Comment: Yeah, encountered that when I tried getting the unpacked extension from arc welder (through the download zip option) and then just scripting the deployment of that as a new extension.  That's a lot more blocked by Chrome than it used to be though as you mentioned.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

just give metadata option {"enableExternalDirectory":true}